# Delay() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I am using delay() in this code but it doesn't work ...

```
   $j(function(){
      $j(".select-plan #container ul li").hover(function(){
         $j(this).find(".checkout-pop-out").delay(500).stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
      },function(){
         $j(this).find(".checkout-pop-out").stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
      });
    });
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: is $j short for jQuery's $. never used that way.

Comment: I am using other JS libraries which make conflicts with jQuery, $j separates jQuery from the other ones so there won't be any conflicts. You can change that... it will be activated after including this before your function `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.delay()` is used for animations first stop the animation and then use delay with `fadeIn`, try

```
   $(function(){
      $(".select-plan #container ul li").hover(function(){
         $(this).find(".checkout-pop-out").stop(true, true).delay(500).fadeIn(200);
      },function(){
         $(this).find(".checkout-pop-out").stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
      });
    });
```

Comment: that makes sense, I tried that before but don't know why it is working now I might doing something wrongly, thank you.